# Как лучше всего сделать?

Tags: php

Пишу экономику, вот заинтересовался одним моментом. У меня будет в экономике такие функции: выдача монет, забрать монеты, установить определенное кол-во на баланс.

Вопрос мой в этом, для каждой из этой функции делать отдельный метод (addMoney, removeMoney, setMoney) или же сдалать 1 метод и в аргументы принимать callback-функцию. Как лучше сделать?)))

Comment: Делайте отдельные методы, а код, который может быть использован в нескольких из этих методов, выносите в отдельный

Comment: А почему лучше отдельные? У них ведь будет одинаковые условия, ток отличаться будут в том, что у addMoney будет +, а у removeMoney будет -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Функция должна иметь одну задачу,
> и делать её хорошо.

Но для удобства можно, рекомендую.
Делайте callback.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).